# Why does adding a memoized function in useEffect dependency array cause an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a function that is being used in my `useEffect` hook and I had to add in the `dependency array`. I also have some other dependencies that are being passed as props from an external component. Because of that dependency function, I had to wrap my function in a `useCallback` for it to avoid to change on every render. But I'm confused why the error is still popping out? And also how should I get accross it ?

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App({uniqueCol,data,handleSelect, unselectAll = false}) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(new Set(""));
  const [currentRows, setCurrentRows] = useState(data);

  //here it is fine when I add currentRows and uniqueCol as dependencies
  const changeSelect = useCallback(
    (id: string, status: boolean) => {
      const cr = currentRows.map((row) => {
        if (uniqueCol) {
          // @ts-ignore
          if (row[uniqueCol] == id) row.selected = status;
        }
        return row;
      });
      setCurrentRows(cr);
    },
    [currentRows, uniqueCol]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    selected.forEach((sel) => changeSelect(sel, true));
    setCurrentRows(data);
  }, [changeSelect, data, selected]);


  /*here it causes errors when I add changeSelect, currentRows, 
          handleSelect as dependencies but works fine when I remove them*/

  const unSelectAll = useCallback(() => {
    setSelected(new Set(""));
    _.map(currentRows, "id").forEach((val) => {
      changeSelect(val, false);
    });

    if (handleSelect) handleSelect([]);
  }, [changeSelect, currentRows, handleSelect]);


//another useEffect that is using the function unSelectAll as a dependency     
useEffect(() => {
         unSelectAll();
      }, [unSelectAll, unselectAll]);

    

  return <h1>Anything here</h1>;
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Comment: could you paste the useEffect code?

Comment: handleSelect comes from out side of the component. It cannot be sure if it is changing or not. Maybe memorizing can help `const memorizedHandler = React.useMemo(()=>handleSelect, [handleSelect]);` then use `memorizedHandler`. If it did not work use useRef.

Comment: I used this one and then this block of code also caused infinite render:

`useEffect(() => {
    selected.forEach((sel) => changeSelect(sel, true));
    setCurrentRows(data);
  }, [changeSelect, data, selected]);`

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have posted doesn't include "the full story", but I feel it is reasonable to assume the following, because you said *"I had to wrap my function in a useCallback for it to avoid to change on every render"*,
but your usage of `useCallback()` has practically no effect here:

`changeSelect` will change on every render, because:

- `changeSelect` has `currentRows` in the dependencies, and
- `changeSelect` calls `setCurrentRows()`

`unSelectAll` will change on every render, because:

- `unSelectAll` has `changeSelect` in the dependencies, and
- `changeSelect` changes on every render

So a simplified version to illustrate the "recursive" dependencies would be:

```
function App(){
  const [currentRows, setCurrentRows] = useState(data);

  const changeSelect = useCallback(
    () => { setCurrentRows([]); },
    [ currentRows, uniqueCol ]
  );

  const unSelectAll = useCallback(
    () => { changeSelect(); },
    [ changeSelect, currentRows ]
  );

  return <>...</>;
}
```

This is only a guess, but probably some other code - probably the `useEffect` which you mentioned, but haven't posted the code - is using `unSelectAll`
as a dependency, and changes maybe `uniqueCol`, so that

- `App` re-renders if `uniqueCol` changes
- `changeSelect` changes on every render
- `unSelectAll` changes because `changeSelect` changes
- `uniqueCol` changes because `unSelectAll` changes (probably ? in some other code ?)

At least probably this is the root cause, and the actual recursive chain (the infinite loop) is closed somewhere else, for this or a similar reason.

Comment: I added that `useEffect` that is using the function `unSelectAll` as a dependency. Can you suggest how I can change my code to avoid the error ?

Comment: I also added some another useEffect that might be crucial.

Comment: How can I make `changeSelect` not changing on every render.

Comment: Don't change a state inside a useEffect if that state is inside the dependencies of the same useEffect. E.g. don't use `currentRows` inside of `changeSelect`, but use [a function in setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) instead. FYI: `row.selected = status` will probably also cause errors later ([never mutate state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)). But ask a new question if needed then.

Comment: `row.selected = status` is happening inside a map so not directly on the state. Also I think mutating the site directly doesn't cause infinite loop, instead it causes some other behaviours. The question is asking the cause of the problem and how to get across it.